# Установка своей скидки в битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Подскажите, может знает кто, как можно в битриксе при оформлении заказа выставить свою произвольную скидку?

т.е я создал поле по типу как купон, человек вводит туда количество баллов и мне надо сделать скидку на такое же количество баллов как указал пользователь. Копаюсь в механизме применения купона DiscountCouponsManager::add но никак не могу найти где меняется цена при установке купона, чтобы использовать в своих целях точное значения для установки скидки 1 балл - 1 рубль.

```
protected function enterCouponAction()
{
    $coupon = trim($this->request->get('coupon'));

    if (!empty($coupon))
    {
        if (DiscountCouponsManager::add($coupon))
        {
            $this->refreshOrderAjaxAction();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->showAjaxAnswer($coupon);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте обратить внимание на "События компонента оформления заказа"  https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/sale/events/event_sale_order_ajax.php , с помощью которых из init.php можно поменять цены до/во время/после оформления заказа

Comment: не подходит, мне нужно в момент оформления заказа, как только меняет юзер количество баллов, выполнять пересчет цены. как то повлиять на нее, ввел пользователь 2 балла, я сделал скидку на 2 балла. События срабатывают не тогда как нужно.

Comment: BX.Core - тоже вариант. Достаточно набрать в консоли браузера window, , чтобы увидеть переменные и наборы данных, которыми можно манипулировать.   Я предполагал, что какая-то простенькая калькуляция в окошках просчитывается по формуле, может даже их простеньких запросов к данным. И вся эта байда записывается из form , далее обрабатывается php обработчиками "при оформлении заказа"